# Shared preferences not setting boolean inside boot_received broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create the option to start my service on boot. The broadcast receiver works great by itself, but when I add in the option it never sets it to true. Here is the code.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("startatboot",0);
      boolean startatboot = prefs.getBoolean("startatboot", false);
      if (startatboot) {
          context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
      }
```

Comment: Have you registered the broadcast receiver for that action?

Comment: yes. it works fine until I add in the boolean. Then it defaults to false

Comment: Could you please add the code where you are setting the boolean to true?

Comment: I edited it, but I know im still doing something wrong.

Comment: Your question helped me find my own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change this...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("startatboot",0);
```

to this...

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);



public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      boolean startatboot = prefs.getBoolean("startatboot", false);
      if (startatboot) {
          context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
      }
```

Comment: Why did you have to change it?