# Broadcast Receiver and Preference Checkbox not working together

Tags: java, checkbox, broadcast, preference, receiver

Any help is appreciated.

I have a Broadcast receiver in the manifest that when is android:enabled="true" receives the broadcast and starts the service. And when it is android:enabled="false" receives no broadcast and service does not start.

This is what you would expect when using PackageManger,when I try to use this with my preference activity the service gets called all the time in the case of android:enabled="true" or android:enabled="false" the service never gets called. In both case it does not matter if the checkbox is checked or not.

I think the problem is in how the preference activity is constructed,in that the true/false logic I have tried is screwed up.I am getting no errors which makes believe it is how the Java is constructed. Really would like some help
on solving this.    Thanks in advance for any help you might offer.

Here is the preference XML and Preference Java.

```
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference

android:key="CheckBox"

 android:id="@+id/CheckBox1" 
 android:title=" StartUp" 
 android:summary="Change The CheckBox Status here, it will be saved in 
 Preference" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And below is the Java

```
package com.collabera.labs.sai;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
mport android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class ShowPreferences extends PreferenceActivity implements     
 OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{
boolean CheckBox;
CheckBox cb;
PreferenceManager pm;
SharedPreferences sp;
Editor editor;
private String CHECKBOX;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.bootpreference);

    cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox1);

    loadPref();}



     private void loadPref() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SharedPreferences sp =        
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
    sp.getBoolean("CHECKBOX", false);}



     private void savePrefs(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sp = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(CHECKBOX, true);
        edit.commit();
     }


         public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        savePrefs("CHECKBOX", cb.isChecked());
        if (cb.isChecked());


       }


       public void pendingIntent()   {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

     public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences  
     sharedPreferences,
        String key, boolean cbValue) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     if(cbValue){
        cb.setChecked(true);

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 
                BroadcastServiceReceiver.class);

         PendingIntent pendingIntent 
            = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 
                    0, myIntent, 0);

         AlarmManager alarmManager 
                = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
         calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
         long interval = 60 * 1000; //
         alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                 calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

         PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
         ComponentName compName = 
               new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
                       BroadcastServiceReceiver.class);
         pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
               compName,
               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, 0);







         }else{
           cb.setChecked(false);

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), 
                 BroadcastServiceReceiver.class);

         PendingIntent pendingIntent 
            = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 
                    0, myIntent, 0);

         AlarmManager alarmManager 
                = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

         alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);


         PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
         ComponentName compName = 
               new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
                       BroadcastServiceReceiver.class);
         pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
               compName,
               PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);}


         }

         @Override
         public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences 
         sharedPreferences,
         String key) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         savePrefs("CHECKBOX", cb.isChecked());
         if (cb.isChecked());


         }

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did not need Package Manager.
Just needed to properly construct the broadcast receiver.

Found at this link.

[Shared preferences not setting boolean inside boot_received broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261678/shared-preferences-not-setting-boolean-inside-boot-received-broadcast-receiver)

Thanks to anyone who had some interest.

Mike